# My Big Query Join isn't returning columns from the second table

Tags: join, google-bigquery, left-join, outer-join

this is really bugging me and I can't figure it out. First of all I'm fairly new using BigQuery and this is the first time I'm trying to combine two tables side by side. What's happening is that the Query runs OK but it doesn't return the columns from the second table. Please assist.

```sql
SELECT
    countryName,
    accountName,
    query as SearchTerm,
    CAST(reportDate AS DATE) AS reportDate,
    campaignName,
    campaignId,
    adGroupName,
    adGroupId,
    keywordId,
    keywordText,
    matchType,
    impressions,
    clicks,
    cost,
    attributedConversions7d as Conversions,
    attributedUnitsOrdered7d as Orders,
    attributedSales7d as Sales

   FROM
    `bold-tooling-306614.Nexus_Big_Query.Amazon_Ads_KeywordReports_1500862413536214_SponsoredProducts_SearchTermKeywordReport` b

    LEFT OUTER JOIN `bold-tooling-306614.Nexus_Big_Query.Branded List` s
    ON b.query = s.Customer_Search_Term
    where b.accountName="XeroShoes"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the content of the second table and the fields that you expect. The easiest solution is to prefix all the projection fields (in the SELECT) by the table where they come from.

```
SELECT b.fieldFromTableFrom, s.fieldFromTableJoin ...
```

You can also set `s.*` to view all the fields.